# `UIScrollView` `bounds` are different in `viewDidAppear` than last `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

In attempt to improve the UI for smaller devices, when a `UIScrollView` `contentSize.height` is greater than it's `bounds.height` (I'm calling this an overflow) I want to tweak the UI.

My issue is: I'm finding the layout of the views is different after appearing on screen (in `viewDidAppear(:)`) than it is in the last `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` (could be called multiple times).
In order to determine if a `scrollView` is overflowing, we need to know both the `scrollView.bounds` and `scrollView.contentSize`. Which I thought would be determined in the last call of `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Below examples my scenario. It's running an interface built in `xib` with the `scrollView` set up there too. Note there are no hiding/showing of views to interfere with the layout values, simply runs through.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    printOverflow(type: #function)
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    printOverflow(type: #function)
}

private func printOverflow(type: String) {
    let isOverflowY = scrollView.contentSize.height > scrollView.bounds.height
    debugPrint("[Overflow] \(type) \(isOverflowY ? "Overflow" : "Fits")")
}

// After running prints:
// "[Overflow] viewDidLayoutSubviews() Fits"
// "[Overflow] viewDidAppear(_:) Overflow"
```

My question is: why can I not get the final layout of the subviews in the last `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`?

I also tried adding a `view.layoutIfNeeded()` in `viewWillAppear(:)`, indeed this fires another `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` as you'd expect but the `bounds` properties are **still** different to that in `viewDidAppear(:)` (despite actually now printing "Overflow")

Answer (score 1):

From Apple's [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621398-viewdidlayoutsubviews) (italics are mine):

> **func viewDidLayoutSubviews()**
>
> When the bounds change for a view controller'€™s view, the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method. *However, this method being called does not indicate that the individual layouts of the view'€™s subviews have been adjusted. Each subview is responsible for adjusting its own layout.*

So, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` can (and will) be called before subviews have been completely configured by auto-layout. That's also why we see `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` being called multiple times during loading / displaying.

If you subclass `UIScrollView` like this:

```
class MyScrollView: UIScrollView {

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        printOverflow(type: #function)
    }

    private func printOverflow(type: String) {
        let isOverflowY = contentSize.height > bounds.height
        debugPrint("MyScrollView {Content Size: \(contentSize.height) Bounds Height: \(bounds.height)} [Overflow] \(type) \(isOverflowY ? "Overflow" : "Fits")")
    }
    
}
```

You'll see that you get the correct heights.

What exactly are trying to do to *"improve the UI for smaller devices"*? There may be other (better?) options...

---

**Edit**

Here's a very simple example showing the sizing at each stage. The custom view changes its height anchor (if necessary) in its `layoutSubviews()` function:

import UIKit

```
class MySizingView: UIView {
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        if frame.height != 200.0 {
            heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200.0).isActive = true
        }
        print(#function, "self height:", frame.height)
    }
}

class SizingTestViewController: UIViewController {

    let myView: MySizingView = {
        let v = MySizingView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        v.backgroundColor = .cyan
        return v
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.addSubview(myView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            // constrain width and center X & Y
            //    its height will be set by its own height constraint
            myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            myView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            myView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        print(#function, "myView height:", myView.frame.height)
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print(#function, "myView height:", myView.frame.height)
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print(#function, "myView height:", myView.frame.height)
    }

}
```

Debug console output should be:

```
viewWillAppear(_:) myView height: 0.0
viewDidLayoutSubviews() myView height: 0.0
layoutSubviews() self height: 0.0
viewDidLayoutSubviews() myView height: 200.0
layoutSubviews() self height: 200.0
viewDidAppear(_:) myView height: 200.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Reading the docs though it also says: "the view adjusts the positions of its subviews and then the system calls this method". So it sounds like it positions it's subviews, those subviews position their own subviews etc. So all the subviews would have finished their layout? Regarding your last question. I was going to hide spaceViews if the scrollView is in overflow.

Comment: @Bechsh - if you give it a try with a subclassed scroll view - including debug print output - you'll see that the order is: controller `viewWillAppear()` followed by controller `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` followed by ***subclass*** `layoutSubviews()` followed by controller `viewDidAppear()`. If I do something in `layoutSubviews()` in my subclass that changes the layout of the controller, the controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is called again.

Comment: @Bechsh - instead of "hiding spacer views" you could probably set their heights as a percentage (or some other relation) and let auto-layout handle it for you.

Comment: @Bechsh - I edited my answer with a simple example to demonstrate the order of calls.

Comment: They are already constrained with proportional height to the safe area, it's only a last resort really. :) Ahh yes OK printing out the lifecycle methods is a great way to be confident here.